# How do we normalize a pointer?

Tags: c, pointers

Actually i was studying about huge and far pointers.
I come to know huge pointers are by default in normalized form.
I want to know how can we normalize any pointer?

Comment: Just FYI far pointers are obsolete. They're only needed in Intel 16-bit architecture (which is not used anymore). See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8727122/explain-the-difference-between-near-far-and-huge-pointers-in-c).

Comment: understand normalization & you understand it's usage... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2877417/what-is-meant-by-normalization-in-huge-pointers

Comment: Whatever it is you're reading, it's outdated. There are no far/near pointers these days. And by "these days" I mean the last 15 years.

Comment: @NikosC. Are you sure? Are you familiar with all platforms, including PIC, avr and all other kinds of µCs? I think there are enough platforms left with several sizes of pointers.

Comment: @glglgl Yes, I'm quite sure that no one would omit this information in a question.

Comment: @NikosC. That's right. But nevertheless the statement "There are no far/near pointers these days." only counts for PCs, not for the embedded world.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The huge pointer and far pointer are old concept which live in 16-bit
DOS time. You can search something about DOS programming for more
detail about them.

In 8086 programming (MS DOS), a far pointer is normalized if its offset part is between 0 and 15 (0xF).